# Django: models.BooleanField(default=False) always save value as 1(True)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have one Boolean model field `payment_received`  which as default value set to False. From the frontend dropdown it as coming as `0` or `1` form.No matter what value from the dropdown I select it is always saved as 1(True) in the table.
I am trying to debug it & I can verify that proper value is coming from the HTML form but after cleaning is done by Django form it is always results in `True` value.

**My Model**

```
class InvoiceHeader(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'invoice_hdr'

    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    campaign = models.ForeignKey(CampaignHeader, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)

    invoice_date = models.DateField()

    invoice_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    cgst = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    sgst = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    igst = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    payment_received = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_no
```

**My Form**

```
class InvoiceHeaderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('invoice_no','invoice_date','campaign','client', 'invoice_amount','cgst','sgst','igst','total_amount','payment_received')

        model = InvoiceHeader

    
    invoice_no = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    invoice_date = forms.DateField()

    client = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Client.objects.all())

    campaign = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CampaignHeader.objects.all())

    invoice_amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    cgst = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    igst = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    sgst = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    total_amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    payment_received = forms.BooleanField()

    def clean_payment_received(self):
        val = self.cleaned_data['payment_received']

        print('TEST1', val) #<---- always True
        return val


    def clean_invoice_no(self):
        invoice_no = self.cleaned_data.get('invoice_no')

        if InvoiceHeader.objects.filter(invoice_no=invoice_no).exists() and not str(self.instance):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invoice no. already exist!')

        return invoice_no
```

**Template**

```
<form action="{{ url }}" method="POST" id="invoice_form">
            
            <input type="hidden" name="edit_mode" value="{% if invoice %}{{'1'}}{% else %}{{'0'}}{% endif %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="card shadow py-2">
                <div class="card-body">

                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="invoice_no">Invoice No.<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" tabindex="1" class="form-control" id="invoice_no"
                                    name="invoice_no" placeholder="Enter campaign name"
                                    value="{% if invoice %}{{invoice.invoice_no}}{% endif %}">
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="client">Client<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <select tabindex="3" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"
                                    id="client" name="client">

                                    {% for client in clients %}
                                    <option data-state="{{client.state}}" id="client" value="{{ client.id }}"
                                        {% if invoice and invoice.client_id == client.id %}{{'selected'}}{% endif %}>
                                        {{ client }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="invoice_amount">Invoice Amount<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" data-type='currency' tabindex="5" class="form-control" id="invoice_amount"
                                    name="invoice_amount" placeholder="Enter invoice amount"
                                    value="{% if invoice %}{{invoice.invoice_amount}}{% endif %}">
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="igst">IGST<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" data-type='currency' tabindex="7" class="form-control" id="igst"
                                    name="igst" placeholder="Enter invoice amount"
                                    value="{% if invoice %}{{invoice.igst}}{% endif %}">
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="payment_received">Payment Received?<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <select tabindex="9" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"
                                    id="payment_received" name="payment_received">

                                    <option value="0" {% if invoice and not invoice.payment_received %}{{'selected'}}{% endif %}>NO</option>
                                    <option value="1" {% if invoice and invoice.payment_received %}{{'selected'}}{% endif %}>YES</option>
                                </select>
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="invoice_date">Invoice Date<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" tabindex="2" class="form-control datepicker" id="invoice_date"
                                    name="invoice_date" placeholder="Enter invoice date"
                                    value="{% if invoice %}{{invoice.invoice_date|date:'d/m/Y'}}{% endif %}">
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="campaign">Campaign<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <select tabindex="4" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"
                                    id="campaign" name="campaign">

                                    {% if invoice %}
                                        {% for campaign in campaigns %}
                                            <option value="{{campaign.id}}"  {% if campaign == invoice.campaign %}{{'selected'}}{% endif %}>{{campaign}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}

                                </select>
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cgst">CSGT<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" data-type='currency' tabindex="6" class="form-control" id="cgst"
                                    name="cgst" placeholder="Enter invoice amount"
                                    value="{% if invoice %}{{invoice.cgst}}{% endif %}">
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="sgst">SGST<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" data-type='currency' tabindex="8" class="form-control" id="sgst"
                                    name="sgst" placeholder="Enter invoice amount"
                                    value="{% if invoice %}{{invoice.sgst}}{% endif %}">
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="total_amount">Total Amount<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" data-type='currency' tabindex="10" class="form-control" id="total_amount" readonly
                                    name="total_amount" placeholder="Enter invoice amount"
                                    value="{% if invoice %}{{invoice.total_amount}}{% endif %}">
                                <small class="error-msg form-text text-danger"></small>
                            </div>

                            

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <br>
            
        </form>
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: show your template code

Comment: can you please add the view code

Comment: @c.grey Template code added

Comment: @RopAliMunshi... can you add `required=Flase` in `payment_received`  in forms.py and check if its working.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha Still no luck...

Comment: @RopAliMunshi, what do you see in `self.data`?

Comment: write a `print(request.POST)`  in view function and check in debug logs.  that is template issue not model forms.

Comment: You're evaluating `if invoice` in the value of the form, what is `invoice` set to in the view context?

Comment: @NKSM I am getting correct value in the self.data

Comment: @JagadeeshKatla I am already doing that I can see the correct value coming from the template

Comment: The only way I am getting correct value is from self.data['payment_received']

Comment: @RopAliMunshi, can you share your `self.data`. [BooleanField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/021f946569d0714fccd090bb2a5f1d7ab2720447/django/forms/fields.py#L702) `if isinstance(value, str) and value.lower() in ('false', '0'): value = False`

Answer (score 0):

This might work (in forms.py). Also can you tell which django version you are using?

```
[...]
    payment_received = forms.BooleanField(widget=CheckboxInput(default=False), required=False)
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

the 'selected' value of the html template will render the booleanfield to True.
Because usually a booleanfield on html-side is a checkbox, which is True if it is selected.